# Error in installing Active admin Gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add Active Admin gem in my Rails Application So i add the following in my gem file. While i run bundle install it thrown me a error " Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sprockets":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) ruby depends on
      sprockets (<= 2.11.0, ~> 2.8) ruby

```
meta_search (>= 1.1.0.pre) ruby depends on
  actionpack (~> 3.1.0.alpha) ruby depends on
    sprockets (2.0.3)
```

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    formtastic (>= 0) ruby depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.2.13) ruby

```
meta_search (>= 1.1.0.pre) ruby depends on
  actionpack (3.1.0.beta1)"

 gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'

 gem 'polyamorous', github: 'activerecord-hackery/polyamorous'

 gem 'ransack', github: 'activerecord-hackery/ransack'

 gem 'formtastic', github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'
 gem "meta_search", '>= 1.1.0.pre'

 gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Meta Search is not maintained any more. Therefore there is only the old version available, which only works with rails 3 and especially action_pack 3.1.x in that case. But you are using rails 4 which requires a newer sprocket version.

You have to migrate from `meta_search` to it's successor `ransack`. It has a slightly different api, but the transition is smooth

Comment: Thanks for answer. Please explain how to migrate.

Comment: Now I just add gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'devise' Now i got this error.Git error: command `git rev-parse rails4` in directory
/home/ameex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/active_admin-d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
'/home/ameex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/cache/bundler/git/active_admin-d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca'

Comment: There is no ralis 4 branch for the active_admin gem. Use master